# iOS - Is there something else that is secure like KeyChain but gets deleted when app is deleted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I have some IAPs hosted with Apple in my app. The IAPs are mainly images.

To track if the users buy my stuff I used KeyChain to store an array of the purchased IAPs.

If the user deletes the app. The contents downloaded from Apple server will be deleted but the array in keychain will stay the same. When the user reinstalls the app and click on the unlocked IAP they will see a blank imageViews.

Here is what I know:

- I cannot know if app gets deleted.
- I cannot reset keychain when the app gets deleted.
- I know that if I store the IAP array in `NSUserDefaults`, I can reset the array if the app gets reinstalled. But `NSUserDefaults` is insecure and I do not want to use it.

I want to securely store an array of purchased IAPs that gets deleted when the app gets deleted.

How do I do this? Is there something else that is secure like KeyChain but gets deleted when app is deleted?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create archived file and store it in app folder or you can use core data have you tried these.

Comment: your sandbox gets deleted when your app is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the most elegant way to do that but that's all I could come up with.
Keep a flag in `NSUserDefaults` like `isFirstLaunch` and at the first launch of your app do your migration tasks: for example, if isFirstLaunch, delete all the IAPs in Keychain.

Migration can always be painful but hope that might help.

Comment: I guess this is a way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could however use `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode your objects and then store them in your `NSUserDefaults`.

**Archive:**
Swift

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourObject)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "yourKey")
```

ObjC

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

**Unarchive:**
Swift

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

ObjC

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

see [here](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)